# extract words matching a pattern and print character length

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a test file which looks like this

file.txt

```
    this is a smart boy "abc.smartxyz" is the name
    what you in life doesn;t matter
    abc.smartabc is here to help you. 
    where is the joy of life
    life is joyous at "https://abc.smart/strings"
```

grep 'abc.smart' file.txt

```
    this is a smart boy "abc.smartxyz" is the name
    abc.smartabc is here to help you. 
    life is joyous at "https://abc.smart/strings"
```

Now I want to be able to extract all words that have the string abc.smart from this grepped file and also print out how many characters they are. Output I am after is something like

```
"abc.smartxyz" 14
abc.smartabc 12
"https://abc.smart/strings" 27
```

Please can someone help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/abc.smart/) print $i,length($i)}' file
```

You can run it directly on the first file. Output:

```
"abc.smartxyz" 14
abc.smartabc 12
"https://abc.smart/strings" 27
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU grep and sed):

```
grep -o '\S*abc\.smart\S*' file | sed 's/"/\\"/g;s/.*/echo "& $(expr length &)"/e'
```

Use grep to output words containing `abc.smart` and sed to evaluate each string to calculate its length using the bash `expr` command.